# External hard disk stopped encrypting part way, freezes when trying to unlock

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, bitlocker

After a hard disk stopped in the middle of an encryption, I can no longer get access to it or unlock it since it keeps freezing up on me.

I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate and have a Western Digital external hard disk and decided to lock it. While encrypting with Bitlocker drive encryption (at 28%) my laptop shut off. I then turned it back on, click on external hard disk and where it now requires me to put my password. I did, but it froze (not responding) when enter my password and click "unlock".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your statement, you were attempting to encrypt an external hard drive and your laptop unexpectedly shut off before the drive was fully encrypted.  If that is the case, I think you have to start over with encrypting your drive, you can't access the hard drive because it is only partially encrypted and the software can't deal with that.  There may be a way to finish the process, but without knowing what drive encryption software you are using (I'm guessing BitLocker) I'm not sure if or how that is possible.

Comment: Yes im using bitlocker the recommended thing..how do i start it over?I cant even enter my hard disk..when i put my password and press unlock it froze(not-reponding)

Comment: so what do you recommend me to do...i hope there is a way bcoz theres alot of imporant files in it..arghhh

Comment: I will admit I am not an expert on BitLocker, but Microsoft does have a BitLocker Recovery Tool that might help [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17294), and a TechNet article that will probably be of help [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523219%28WS.10%29.aspx).  Regarding the files on the drive, you should **always** make sure you have files backed up before you do something like this.  I'm sorry if you lost important data on this.

Comment: i tried the bitlocker recovery tool but it says it doesnt work on windows 7 ultimate.I'll try the TechNet..actually i just wanted to set a password for my external hard disk nothing more thn that but the procedure said that i must encrypt it first thn only it is locked.If i send it to any pc repair centre,do you think they can fix it?bcoz the encrypt just only less thn 28%